# rails form post action without changing path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I've got a view that renders a contact form. This contact form is rendered through javascript. There is also a javascript filter that the user can set viewing options in. (Depending on the settings, different markers are shown on a google map. The user can then click on the markers and in the viewbox click on a view button that renders some info and the contact form below the map)

If I were to make a normal form and use the post method with a `@contact` and contact routes, I would have to rerender the entire page after the `@contact#create` method was called. Which would mean all of the current users filter options would be unset. I could obviously save the settings, but feel like this is a hassle.

What I would like is for the contact form to call a method upon submit without actually changing paths, but I have no idea if this is even possible. (i'm using simple form so an answer for that would be preferable)

Comment: Use ajax to save your data. This link will help you understand how. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is quite broad, I'll have to answer as such:

---

> if this is even possible

Yes it's possible.

You'll have to use [`ajax`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to send an *asynchronous* request to your server.

**Ajax** (***A***synchronous **J**avascript **A**nd **X**ml) sends requests out of scope of typical HTTP; you can send/receive "hidden" data **without reloading** (this is what you want):

[image]

**Don't worry** - ajax is really simple once you understand it.

There's a great Railscast about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBxVN7U1Qsk):

[image]

---

**Implementation**

For you, you will just have to get your form to submit over ajax (javascript). There are two ways to do this:

> 1. Standard JS (JQuery)
> 2. Rails UJS (unobtrusive [Javascript](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs))

Basically, javascript acts as a mini browser, opening a url on your server, handling the returned data & doing what you tell it on the path:

```
<% form_tag contact_path, remote: true %>
   <%= text_field_tag "name %>
   <%= email_field_tag "email" %>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

You'll then be able to back this up with the corresponding controller action on your server:

```
#app/controllers/contact_forms_controller.rb
class ContactFormsController < ApplicationController
   def create
     ... #-> your own logic here
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js #-> when receiving a pure xml request, this will fire
       format.html
     end
   end
end

#app/views/contact_forms/create.js.erb
$("body").append("<%=j @variable %>");
```

Without going into too much detail, this is the most efficient way to achieve what you want. I can elaborate if required.